# facebook-unity-sdk parse.com can't get it working

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, facebook-unity-sdk

I try to add facebook sdk on my unity game with following the tutorial ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/tutorials/games/ setup part) i follow the instruction and use parse.com for deploy the game because i don't have web server but i don't understand how to use parse.com for deploy the game there is no option for upload file, its possible to upload it (and how?) or it's a feature only reserved for Pro/enterprise plan ?

(Otherwise what web service i can use for deploy a unity webplayers? other than dropbox)

Answer (score 2):

Solved found the parse.zip for the parse console and can upload with it

Comment: Can you post a link to console instructions? I think a few people have had trouble with this.

Comment: https://parse.com/downloads/windows/console/parse.zip  for the console parse.zip


https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-installing
for instruction